# white-space:nowrap does not work properly with Flying Saucer

Tags: java, html, pdf, flying-saucer

I am using Flying Saucer to convert HTML documents to PDF. But there is a problem when I use `<span style="white-space:nowrap">`

Generally `white-space:nowrap` works fine. But when the span is near the right-margin of the document, it gets trimmed.

For example:

This HTML:

```
This is fine. <span style="white-space:nowrap">This is a test</span>
```

gets converted to PDF like this:

[image]

which is perfect.

But when I use:

```
This is fine. This is also fine. <span style="white-space:nowrap">This is a test</span>
```

it gets converted to:

[image]

Notice that part of the span is trimmed because of the right margin.
What I expect is:

[image]

i.e. I expect the span to move to the next line.

The code I am using to convert to PDF is:

```java
String inputFile = "test.html";
String url = new File(inputFile).toURI().toURL().toString();
String outputFile = "firstdoc.pdf";
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.setDocument(url);
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(os);

os.close();
```